# In C how does a array of struct look in memory

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to understand how does a array of structs look like in memory. Suppose I have the following

```
struct b{
     int x;
     int y;
     int z;
};
b barray[100];
```

So now barray is an array of structs where barray is the pointer to the 1st struct i.e. barray=&barray[0]. 
If int is taking 2 bytes and then say the struct b takes 6 bytes and lets say barray = 1000 and the size of pointer is say 4 bytes. Then is barray+1=1004 or is it 1006? 
I mean is the array an array of pointers each pointing to its instance of the structure or are all the 100 structures placed in a continuous memory location and incrementing the index of the array jumps to the next struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is a contiguous block of memory in c, so an array of structs will have a size of `sizeof(struct b)*number_of_structs`. All of the structs are allocated within the array.

Note that in your example `sizeof(struct b)` is not guaranteed to be 6 because the compiler is allowed to insert padding to byte align the structs - you can use "packed" to avoid this if you like but it may hinder performance. [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)